# How to restore ubuntu os

Tags: linux, crash, ubuntu-10.04

My Hdd got some bad sectors and I had to reboot my PC. Now I am not able to log in. The OS is booting and then I get a message on the login screen "GNome settings are not configured ..." So the thing I am not even able to log into the system because of gnome failure and not getting shell access to the system. In this case how to recover my PC. Ubuntu is the only OS on my PC. Please help

Regards,
Chaitannya

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions and not for system installation questions. Please move this to Stack Exchange or other sites

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a bootable Ubuntu on a DVD.  Perhaps you could even boot from the DVD you installed the operating system from.

So, put the Ubuntu DVD into the reader, turn the machine on and you should get into a minimal system.  From there, you could try and mount your hard drive and, if successful, reconfigure the GNome or at least extract your files to another drive.

I run my Linux system with 2 drives; a small drive that contains the OS itself and a large drive to house my files.  That way, if I get a HD error on the OS drive, I can replace it with a new one.  If I get a HD on the large drive, I can still start up the OS.

Good Luck